# Чем отличается процедура от функции на примере языка java?

Tags: java, функции, методы, процедуры

Насколько я знаю, функции в java называются методами, но что тогда из себя представляют процедуры, может быть статические методы?

Comment: Ничего. В java нет процедур.

Comment: в гугле забанили? @Bakhuss, что значит в java нет процедур??? при чём тут вообще ЯП

Comment: @timbars если Вы такой умный, то скиньте ссылку на документацию java о процедурах?

Comment: для тех кто не понимает, что java не имеет никакого отношения к терминам процедура и функция(и разумеется не важно есть такое слово в документации или нет....), есть топик enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721090/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-procedure

Comment: в java нет терминов ни функция ни процедура, вместо них используется термин - метод (возвращающий или не возвращающий значения)

Comment: @pavlofff, с этого момента поподробнее, пожалуйста)
Что является в java аналогом процедур?

Comment: в java нет аналога функций и процедур в полном понимании этого термина, так как java не допускает функций верхнего уровня и любой исполняемый блок кода может принадлежать только какому то объекту (в т.ч. статическому классу). Упрощенно для java можно считать метод, который возвращает значение - аналогом функции, а void-метод (не возвращающий значение) - аналогом процедуры.

Comment: @timbars, во-первых, вам стоит почитать это: [Нормы поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct). Во-вторых, заголовок вопроса звучит так: `"Чем отличается процедура от функции на примере языка java?"` - это отвечает на ваш вопрос `"при чём тут вообще ЯП"` - при том что вопрос про процедуры и функции в контексте Java. В-третьих, в Java действительно нет процедур.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В java нет процедур. Другое дело с функциями, в Java они называются методами, а методы в свою очередь могут либо возвращать значения(int, String ... и т.д.), либо не возвращать(void). По крайней мере лично я слово "процедуры" еще не разу не встречал ни в одной книжке по Java. К слову в "Философия Java" там автор сразу дает понять, что к методам нужно так же относиться как и к функциям в других языках, но с процедурами параллели вообще не приведены. В любом случае, Вам следует отказаться от данного термина в Java.